# pc crashing none-stop involving dxgkrnl.sys /

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, bsod, dell-inspiron

having my pc crashing on daily-basis 3 times a day for a week

this what came out from whoCrashed software :

> On Sun 12/14/2014 8:35:02 PM GMT your computer crashed
>   crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\121414-18921-01.dmp
>   This was probably caused by the following module: dxgkrnl.sys (dxgkrnl+0x1946D) 
>   Bugcheck code: 0x100000EA (0xFFFFE00086CB7040, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
>   Error: THREAD_STUCK_IN_DEVICE_DRIVER_M
>   file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
>   product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
>   company: Microsoft Corporation
>   description: DirectX Graphics Kernel
>   Bug check description: This indicates that a thread in a device driver is endlessly spinning.
>   This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
>   The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.

my pc is: dell inspiron 15R - 7520 | my mother-board died last week , having my warranty they replaced it for me..

i have unistalled all my drivers through Device Manager thinking it would fix the problem..

it keep crashing.. so now i'm having all my drivers up-to-date for the moment and it still crashing none=stop.

Comment: install the latest Intel driver: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=HD%20Graphics%204000 and AMD 14.12 driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows+8.1+-+64

Comment: @Ramhound can you guide me how to do so?

Comment: @Ramhound http://tny.cz/c00ec01d